# Permission denied on SBT installation

Tags: unix, sbt, chmod

So I "installed" SBT by following directions [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Setup) under the "UNIX" section by downloading the `jar` and creating the `sbt` script to run it - however instead of putting it in `~/bin/` I put it in `/usr/local/sbt/`. I added it to my `PATH` variable and when I try to run it without `sudo` I get a Permission denied error (below). Also below is what I see when I type in `ls -l` in the `sbt` directory.

```
$ sbt compile
bash: /usr/local/sbt/sbt: Permission denied

-rwxrwxr--  1 root       wheel      120 Jun 20 09:21 sbt*
-rwxrwxr--@ 1 adelbertc  staff  1096763 Jun 20 09:20 sbt-launch.jar*
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the permissions so that you can execute it:

```
sudo chmod o+x /usr/local/sbt/sbt /usr/local/sbt/sbt-launch.jar
```

Otherwise, you can add yourself to the `wheel` group, or change the owner so that you own it:

```
sudo chown adelbertcs:staff /usr/local/sbt/sbt
```

(assuming that your username is `adelbertcs`).